# How to avoid methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have a method in which i find date and time with regex as follows:-

```
def find_date_time(params)
    date_pattern = %r{\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}}
    time_pattern = /(\d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{2}\:\d{2})/
    date = params.to_s[date_pattern]
    return unless date
    date_array = date.split('/')
    if date_array.last.length == 2
      date = date_array.replace([date_array.first,
                                 date_array.second,
                                 '20' + date_array.third])
                       .join('/')
    end
    time = params.to_s.scan(time_pattern)
    Time.strptime(date +
                  ' ' +
                  (time.present? ? time.uniq.flatten.last : ''),
                  (time.present? ? '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' : '%d/%m/%Y'))
  end
```

Its works fine but when i run my unit testing `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake` it returns an error `Methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1)` I am using rubocop-rspec. Please help me how can i reduce the complexity of my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using `Date.parse` or `Time.parse`, so the standard library can take care of all that for you?

Comment: I used Time.parse but i got the same error. time = params.to_s.scan(time_pattern) this line cause the Methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1). is there any method which can return the last match of regex.

Comment: There's a way to disble any given rubocop rule in a block of code: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md#disabling-cops-within-source-code But I agree that you should probably find out why Time.parse isn't working first... better than having to maintain your own partial version of an existing, well-tested standard library.

Comment: To return the last match of a regex, have a look at the Regexp docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html  the return-value of a regex-match is matchdata and it can be treated kinda like an array of matches.

Comment: Thanks but Time.parse isn't an issue its working at my end but the method i am using to find the pattern params.to_s.scan(time_pattern)  this is the reason of Methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1).

Comment: As with your other question, this message is coming from Cane, not RuboCop.

Comment: You are right @AndyWaite but please help me how to refactor my code to avoid this?